# print-out database on c# which has type 'TIMESTAMP'

Tags: c#

I'm using a query in C#.  I'm printing out data from a database.

Its number of columns is about 200 and the first column's type is `TIMESTAMP`.

Other types don't have a problem being printed out.  Only TIMESTAMP does.

Someone said I can use `TIMESTAMP` to get `TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME, 'YYYYHHDD')`

I want to show all of database. But if I want, I should type all of column.
This way newly created columns aren't shown.

I want to use query like this, but it doesn`t work:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TIME, 'HHMMSS'), * FROM DATAS
```

Please help me with this query.

Comment: What do you mean by "But if I want, I should type all of column"?

Comment: TimeStamp datatype is not Time datatype.
Consider it like a Binary datatype.

Comment: What database? In SQL Server TIMESTAMP is an ever incrementing binary type that is guaranteed to be unique in a single database. It has no relation to time at all. It is used to detect concurrency conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

SELECT CONVERT(numeric(20,0), stamp + 0) FROM ...

This is where "stamp" is timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you have to read the timestamp value as a byte array and convert it to string. The [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) on MSDN show that Timestamp maps to Byte[]  and can be accessed by the GetSqlBinary or GetBytes methods.

The mapping also shows that [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is actually a row version number that changes automatically each time a row is modified. It has nothing to do with time. It's just an incrementing 8 byte number. This number has no meaning for end-users and there is probably no point in showing it anywhere.

If you still want to display it, you can convert the timestamp bytes to an Int64 type using the [BitConverter.ToInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64.aspx) method.